# Improving framerate of ios game

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, concurrency, frame-rate

I have a simple iOS game nearing completion. It runs quite smoothly on new devices, however running it on an iPhone 4S with iOS 7 is hopeless.

Time profiling it, it seems that a lot of computing power is used on setting the `center` property of `UIViews`, which are set every frame on multiple objects on the screen at any time. Running these functions concurrently using `dispatch_async` results in very weird behavior in which the different objects in the game do not move at the time or speed that they are supposed to.

I have found no way in which I can speed things up a little.

This is a simple 2D game, it should not take this toll on an iOS device.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell us more about how you are doing this. Are you doing animation with a timing loop, setting the center property on views for each frame? If so, that doesn't make very efficient use of the graphics hardware in iOS. A 4s is a fairly recent device. It's still in wide use (my phone is a 4s) and you should be able to support it.

I get 30-60 FPS out of both a 4s and an iPad 2 doing mesh transformations on images using OpenGL, so it is possible.

The time to do performance testing on your lowest-performing target device is "early and often" during development, not when you are nearing completion.

Unfortunately, the answer may be major changes to the way you're doing your animation. Again, you need to provide more details.

Comment: In my edited question, I state that the `center` property is set on multiple `UIView`s every frame. If this is not an efficient use of the graphics hardware, what other methods may I employ to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a delta time on your `update:` method? It should improve performance based on hardware. If you're not using it yet, here is how you do it, considering that you have a player property on a separate class, for example:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSTimeInterval previousUpdateTime;

- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime
{

  NSTimeInterval delta = currentTime - self.previousUpdateTime;

  if (delta > 0.02) {
    delta = 0.02;
  }

  self.previousUpdateTime = currentTime;
 [self.player update:delta];

  ...
}
```

Comment: This is indeed how my `update:` method works, this does not seem to be the source of the error.

Comment: OK. Maybe Duncan's answer will help you more to solve your problem.